# apt-get remove package that didn't install properly

Tags: apt, dependencies, remove

I accidentally installed `zabbix-frontend-php` that pulled `apache2` as a dependency.

I don't want to use either, and I want to completely delete both packages.

Unfortunately, it seems that `apt-get` won't let me remove zabbix until I make apache2 work properly for zabbix. I really don't want to spend time fixing broken packages I'm about to delete.

How can I override apt-get and proceed with deletion?

```
$ apt-get remove apache2 zabbix-frontend-php
Package 'apache2' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apache2-bin apache2-data
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  zabbix-frontend-php
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 28.2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
(Reading database ... 28117 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing zabbix-frontend-php (1:2.4.7-1+jessie) ...
Job for apache2.service failed. See 'systemctl status apache2.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "restart" failed.
dpkg: error processing package zabbix-frontend-php (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 zabbix-frontend-php
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The question and answer here should help:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/438345/how-to-remove-install-a-package-that-is-not-fully-installed

As I read it either of these commands should do what you need:

```
apt-get --force-yes remove <pkgname>

dpkg -r <pkgname>
```